# shows that: $X_n \to 0$ in probability if and only if $\lim_{n \to \infty} E[|X_n|/(1+|X_n|)]=0$

Tags: probability

For the first leg I know that by definition of convergence in probability I have to
$\lim_{n \to \infty }P(|X_n|>\epsilon) =0$
And I think I can use that
$Y_n = |X_n|/(1+|X_n|)$
But then I don't know how to proceed
Thanks, Leo

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This has been answered on this site before